# differentiable curve, its polygonal converges?

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry

Let $$
\alpha :\left[ {a,b} \right] \to R^3 
$$ be a differentiable curve, and let 
 $ a= t_0 < .... < t_n = b $ a partition
consider
$$
\eqalign{
  & L\left( {\alpha ,P} \right) = \sum\limits_{i = 1}^n {\left| {\alpha \left( {t_i } \right) - \alpha \left( {t_{i - 1} } \right)} \right|}   \cr 
  & P = \max (\left( {t_i  - t_{i - 1} } \right),i = 1..n) \cr} 
$$
Prove that given any $$
\varepsilon  > 0
$$
 there exist a $$
\delta  > 0
$$
 such that if $$
\left| P \right| < \delta 
$$
then
$$
\left| \int_a^b \left| \frac{d}{dt}\alpha(t)\right|\,dt - L(\alpha ,P)\right| < \varepsilon 
$$

Comment: I think the inner absolute value in the final display could use fixing.

Comment: ...and the outer is kinda useless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few hints, which I can expand if need be. I assume that your curve is $C^1$.

When you see an equation like the last one, in which the derivative is related to some finite sum of differences, your mind should jump to the [mean value theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem). Use this to find, for each $i = 1, \ldots, n$ and $j = 1, 2, 3$, an $s_{ij} \in [t_i, t_{i + 1}]$ such that
$$
(\alpha_j)'(s_{ij}) = \frac{\alpha_j(t_i) - \alpha_j(t_{i - 1})}{t_i - t_{i - 1}}.
$$

Another observation is that because $\alpha'$ is a continuous function on the compact set $[a, b]$, it is even [uniformly continuous](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_continuity). For a given $\varepsilon$, it follows that if in the above $P$ is small enough then for $i, j$ and any $t \in [t_i, t_{i - 1}]$ we have $|(\alpha_j)'(t) - (\alpha_j)'(s_{ij})| < \varepsilon$. So
$$
|\alpha'(t) - ((\alpha_j)'(s_{ij}))_{j = 1}^3| < \sqrt{3}\varepsilon.
$$

Putting this together involves some careful manipulations using the triangle inequality and some annoying square roots. Good luck!